# In C, Define a structure type element_t to represent one element from the periodic table of elements

Tags: c

I'm writing a code in C and it doesn't give me any errors, but I am not getting the desired result.

Define a structure type element_t to represent one element from the periodic table of elements. Components should include the atomic number (an integer); the name, chemical symbol, and class (strings); a numeric field for the atomic weight; and a seven element array of integers for the number of electrons in each shell. the following are the components of an element_t structure for sodium. 11 sodium Na alkali_metal 22.9898 2 8 1 0 0 0 0 Define and test I/O functions scan_element and print_element.

Once I compile and test the code, this is the output I get
11   ÿ   sodNa   Na   22.989800   2810000%

as you can see, it does  not give me the the element name or the class of element.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define ELEM_NAME 15
#define ELEM_CLASS 20
#define ELECT 7

  typedef struct
  {
    int atom_num;
    char name[ELEM_NAME];
    char symbol[3];
    char class_of_metal [ELEM_CLASS];
    double atomic_weight;
   nt elec[ELECT];
  } element_t;

element_t scan_element();

void print_element(element_t my_element);

element_t

scan_element(); 

int main(void)
{

  int i = 0;
  element_t my_element;

  printf("enter the atomic number:\n");
  scanf("%d", &my_element.atom_num);

  printf("enter element name:\n");
  scanf("%s", &my_element.name[ELEM_NAME]);

  printf("enter symbol:\n");
  scanf("%s", &my_element.symbol[3]);

  printf("enter type of metal:");
  scanf("%s", &my_element.class_of_metal[ELEM_CLASS]);

  printf("enter atomic weight:");
  scanf("%lf", &my_element.atomic_weight);

  printf("enter number of electrons in each shell:");
  scanf("%d", &my_element.elec[ELECT]);

 /* output */
    printf("%d   %s   %s   %s   %lf   %d", my_element.atom_num,
                                           my_element.name,
                                           my_element.symbol,
                                           my_element.class_of_metal,
                                           my_element.atomic_weight,
                                           my_element.elec[ELECT]);

 return (0);
 }
```

Comment: What about the output is "not desired"?

Answer (score 3):

You're misunderstanding how you are supposed to `scanf()` strings into arrays. For example,

```
&my_element.name[ELEM_NAME]
```

points past the end of the element (it seems to me that you think `scanf()` needs this information, but no, it doesn't), so you're writing out of the bounds of the arrays.

So you should change all these erroneous function calls into

```
scanf("%s", my_element.name);
scanf("%s", my_element.symbol);
scanf("%s", my_element.class_of_metal);
scanf("%d", my_element.elec);
```

respectively.

(Also, please read up on arrays, pointers and pointer arithmetic. This is way too basic...)

Comment: I think you need to leave out the & operator for strings from your fixed code. Array variable name is same as address of the first element already, without the &

Comment: @hyde it's not necessary, the value is the same with or without the addressof operator. I prefer leaving it in, since it's safe to do so if the type of the struct member ever changes from an array type to a scalar. (Only the types differ, but it doesn't matter in this case).

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your advice. H2CO3: I've only been writing c for about two month, prior to that, I had absolutuley no programming experience. It's an intro course and and I understand the concepts, the class is just so fast paced that it is hard to learn how to apply it into the code.warning: format â%sâ expects argument of type âchar *â, but argument 2 has type âchar (*)[15]â [-Wformat]

Comment: I followed both of you suggestions. I had compiled my program before just as you suggested H2CO3 but it gives me this error for every scanf line

Comment: @user1673803 that warning is generated because of what hyde mentioned.

Comment: hyde: I also followed your suggestions and i get the same error as above.

Comment: @user1673803 also this is not an error, this is a warning. Here, for the same reason I just explained to hyde, you can safely ignore it.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I ignored them and it works now. Thank you so much!

Comment: `scanf("%s", &my_element.name);` invokes undefined behaviour, `&my_element.name` is a `char (*)[15]`, but the `%s` format requires a `char*`. It won't be easy to find a platform where the type mismatch actually does harm, but it's better to be type-correct and safe.

Comment: @DanielFischer You're right, I updated my answer to get rid of the UB.